# How to delete all images saved in /Android/media/<package name>

Tags: android

I use FileProvider in my code, which automatically save images captured with camera into `/Android/media/com.app.surveyapp`, like this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.app.surveyapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

CaptureActivity.java

```
btnCapture.setOnClickListener(v -> {
File file = new File(getExternalMediaDirs()[0], System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
});
```

How to empty that directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RemoveImageFiles()
{
    try
    {
        String path = Constants.IMG_FILEPATH;
        int FIndex;
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            FName = files[i].getName();
            File FilesName=new File(path + File.separator + FName);
            FilesName.delete();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        seterror(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `File directory = new File(path);` That should be: `File directory = getExternalMediaDirs()[0];` if this should be an answer to the question.

Comment: Further it is not recursive and you are not checking the return value of .delete(). Or if there are subfolders.

Comment: And `files[i].delete();` is more direct then buildig up a new File instance where there is already one available. For the rest anta40 can say Thank you to you ;-).

Comment: @blackapps... Ah, why did I forget about `getExternalMediaDirs()[0]`... thank you :)